# Call php function in json url?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, instagram-api

this is probably a VERY stupid question but I'm a bit new into this so please help me out. I have written a mini code using instagram API that loads photos from a specific location, using the location id. Now what I want to achieve is that use this for a wordpress website i'm building that lists some hotels and restaurants. I've defined the location id as a custom field, so I need to use the following code to call it:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Instagram', true); ?>
```

And my url to call the photos is the following:

```
<?php $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/LOCATION-ID-HERE/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=6");?>
```

The above code works if i insert a location id manually. What I want to achieve is insert the above code into the "location-id-here" part. I guess this is quite simple but I'm kind of confused as both are php functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you're putting in fetchData() is just a string, so you can concatenate output from another function into that string with the `.` operator:

```
<?php 
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Instagram', true) . "/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=6");
?>
```